# cmake add_subdirectory don't compile correctly

Tags: c, cmake, arm

I'm writing a CMakeLists.txt with this content:

```
project(FullLibrary C)
enable_language(C ASM)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Asf")
```

Asf is a library from Atmel to be built on microprocessors. I can compile it directly if I compile it from inside this file. What I did is create another file inside the directory with this content:

```
set ( ASF_SOURCES 
   source_files_removed_for_brevity.c
)
add_library(asf4arm  ${ASF_SOURCES} ) 
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(asf4arm PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C )# CXX ASM)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(asf4arm PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

The error I receive when I compile is:
fatal error: opening dependency file Asf_arm/CMakeFiles/asf4arm.dir/Asf/sam/drivers/usart/usart.c.obj: No such file or directory
I checked and the directory is empty, but I don't have any compiling error.
If I copy and paste the list inside the main CMakeLists.txt and I update the path everything compile correctly and the library is correctly generated.
I think I'm missing something stupid that another eye can see.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your project_sourc_dir variable does not have path set up properly.

Try, changing add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Asf") to add_subdirectory(Asf)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Nick. I already tryed it. I rechecked now but it does not work. The error is the same. Thank you for your try.

Comment: Looks like the directory name is wrong. It looks like the dir name is Asf4Arm instead of just Asf..

Comment: yes. I noticed it. I just don't understand why. A possible bug with cross compiling toolchains? Today will be here the guy that set it up at first. He knows cmake a lot better than me. I'll see if he figures out the problem.

Comment: make sure you are building the library in the same folder as you are listing the sources..